# 'Printing' magnetic polarity into a material

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

There is a company out there that 'prints' magnetic pixels, a.k.a. maxels, into a material.

In doing so, they're able to choose the distance of effect of magnetic fields they create, independently of the magnitude of the field, leading to some really interesting properties.

Can anyone shed some light upon how theyre able to 'print' a 'maxel' into a material?

[Here is a good video by Smarter Every Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IANBoybVApQ) about this company and their process.

Comment: Here is a list of patents from their website. http://www.cmrpatents.com/

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. I assume they are using a blank of NdFe magnetic material and then using a small area coil which is then pulsed to create a programming field. Same way as a conventional magnet is magnetized. However, their coil will have a much smaller diameter and can be moved across the magnet blank in X-Y steps to create multiple magnetic domains within the same blank.

Note that magnetic hard drives do this to the rotating platter billions of times to store the data.

Comment: Perhaps 'billions and billions' is the right phrase? Or these days billions _of_ billions given hard drive sizes!